# Define some variables to be real within the whole notebook

Tags: symbolic

I want to define some variables to be real within the whole notbook? How can I do this? In the following you can find my code. I think the last step will be computed in seconds when I tell mathematica that p,r and z are real!

```
Er = Ert[r, z]*Exp[-I*p];
Ep = Ept[r, z]*Exp[-I*p];
Ez = Ezt[r, z]*Exp[-I*p];

Ei = {(Er*Cos[p] - Ep*Sin[p])*Exp[-I*p] + (Er*Cos[p] + Ep*Sin[p])*
     Exp[I*p], (Er*Sin[p] + Ep*Cos[p])*
     Exp[-I*p] + (Er*Sin[p] - Ep*Cos[p])*Exp[I*p], Ez*2 Cos[p]};
Hi = Simplify[{Sin[p]*D[Ei[[3]], r] + Cos[p]/r*D[Ei[[3]], p] - 
     D[Ei[[2]], z], 
    D[Ei[[1]], z] - Cos[p]*D[Ei[[3]], r] + Sin[p]/r*D[Ei[[3]], p], 
    Cos[p]*D[Ei[[2]], r] - Sin[p]/r*D[Ei[[2]], p] - 
     Sin[p]*D[Ei[[1]], r] - Cos[p]/r*D[Ei[[1]], p]}];
Si = 1/2*Cross[Ei, Conjugate[Hi]]
Integrate[Si[[3]], {p, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `$Assumptions = {Element[{p,e,z},Reals}` to the beginning of your notebook.

Comment: Adding $Assumptions = {Element[{p, r, z}, Reals]} does not work. I still get terms like Conjugate[p] in my expression for SI...

Comment: I also tried Assuming[{p \[Element] Reals, r \[Element] Reals},
 Integrand = Simplify[Si[[3]]];
 Integrate[Integrand, {p, 0, 2*Pi}]
 ], but it still takes ages to calculate the integral

Comment: I think your comment was correct. It seems that one has to simplify the expression such that mathematica uses the global assumption in the simplify process. Many thanks!

Comment: But the problem, that it takes ages to compute the integral remains...

Comment: Only functions having the `Assumptions` option are affected by `$Assumptions`. Note that this setting is not local to the notebook.

Comment: Do you have an advice for the Integral then? Or do I have to simplify it manually?